# Colcon Tutorial on Dashing does not build

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 18.04 running Dashing
on hash bafddbdb of master

The example from the Colcon Tutorial does not build.

https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/

I kept getting errors like this from colcon :

Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"example_interfaces" with any of the following names:

```
example_interfacesConfig.cmake
example_interfaces-config.cmake_
```

I grepped through the commit logs of this repo and 64128033 seemed like the cause - so I cloned https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces into  my src directory such that my filesystem was like this

---- src

-------- examples

--------  example_interfaces

and Cmake stopped complaining about an unknown dependency.

After that I got a build error on master, went to the dashing branch and got farther, but I kept getting more colcon errors, and after cloning the following three repos into my src directory colcon built for me

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp
https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces
https://github.com/ros2/test_interface_files

my final directory structure looked like this:
.

---- src

-------- examples

--------  example_interfaces

--------  rcl_interfaces

--------  test_interface_files

Did I miss a step in my install or is that tutorial lacking these steps?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327356/colcon-tutorial-on-dashing-does-not-build/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2019-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have not sourced the ROS2 SDK before building your new workspace: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/#source-an-underlay

```
cd <path_to_ros2_ws>
source install/setup.sh
```

For the following errors, I think that you may have mixed different versions of SDK and examples repositories.
Ensure that both of them are up to date to the distribution that you are using (Dashing).

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2023-07-27**:
I have the same issue with humble